# User Operation is waiting for "Building Workspace"

Tags: android, eclipse

As the title mentioned, I have developed a simple NFC app in eclipse and I am trying to run it in the mobile device to debug my code. However, when I try to run it, this message came out, the problem even cannot launch. It said one operation left, but it seems like it has stopped. Have anyone met the similar problem before, or anyone know what is happening here?

[image: The screen comes out when I run the program]

Comment: Vote for https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329657 - An active build blocks user task (like save)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. For me helped adding '-clean' option at the first line of eclipse.ini file and restarting IDE. After adding this option eclipse clean all cached data in workspace each time it is started (that also mean it will be starting slower).

You can find more information about it here: [How to repair hanging 'User Operation is waiting for “Building Workspace”' in eclipse](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html)

Answer (score 20):

For me the clean option didn't work and I didn't want to reset the workspace. Fortunately for me another solution worked:

1. Disable automatic builds (uncheck menu item Projects -> Build Automatically)
2. Restart IDE (I had to kill it from command line)
3. Close all projects
4. Restart IDE (this time it should close without problems)
5. Open projects that you need to work on (everything should be fine now)

Oh yeah, I had the clean option in the eclipse.ini the entire time. Not sure if that is necessary, but it might be good to try that option first anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I had to disable the automatic build option from the Eclipse and restart it. This made it work for me.

Answer (score 3):

This method worked for me:

1. Go to menu 'Project' -> uncheck 'Build Automatically'.
2. Force close Eclipse then reopen it.
3. Delete the class files.
4. Edit the source codes which caused the error, save, and rebuild the project ('Project' -> 'Build All').

Hope this'll help!

Answer (score 2):

I got this solved by removing `<workspace_folder>/.metadata/.lock` file.

Comment: That was precisely what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: dying waiting for Project/clean.
I have tried following this recommandations, "-clean" comman in eclipse.ini, modified the working environment, reinstall eclipse...
After all, problem stayed still.

Then finally, I ask my friend, then the solution was simple: "it might be crashed at your aapt file, change it with a good one"

Everything works fine now.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be an indication that the JDK setting is wrong in Eclipse. In my case, I was pointing to a specific directory on my work computer. The IT people upgraded the JDK and put it in a different directory so the old path was no longer valid. Eclipse did find a JRE in a parallel directory and was trying to use that.

I fixed the JDK setting and it worked.

I didn't notice at first because I had "build automatically" turned on. Once I turned it off then tried to run a Maven build, then I saw an error message saying javac couldn't be found.

Answer (score 0):

this can be due to installing another software with port setted equivalent to the port used by adb server

[adb hangs when trying to start or stop server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116121/adb-hangs-when-trying-to-start-or-stop-server/17118322#17118322)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I applied what the fellows had advised however it didn't work. I figured out that there were some folders under target-->classes directory that neither myself nor the IDE was able to clean/delete..
I restarted the machine then started the IDE and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Project** Menu **Uncheck** the **Build automatically** and **Restart** the **Eclipse**/STS IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was due to incorrect build path of the maven project. Try configuring the build path and include only what is actually required is what i learnt.
My parent maven project had 10+ child modules. My eclipse would take 3-4 mins waiting for background process for every file save. I removed [parent module]/src from the build path and restarted eclipse and issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case the problem was I had so many files in my project. I was working working on a [corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus) and the corpus had more than 88000 files. I moved the files to outside of the project and everything started working as normal.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue and the reason was there was one project it was not build correctly. so if you ran into this issue in an existing working workspace review the recent changes or recently imported projects.