# the user operation is waiting for background work to complete

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse junno for my IDE for developing android programs.

my problem is just like this one :
[User Operation is waiting for "Building Workspace"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514987/user-operation-is-waiting-for-building-workspace)

why did it happened and how can I solve this?
I have waited lots of time about this case.

right now it is look like this.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [User Operation is waiting for "Building Workspace"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514987/user-operation-is-waiting-for-building-workspace)

Comment: The question linked above includes a number of other suggestions, including a link to a detailed article.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Eclipse can have a tendency to hang sometimes for no apparent reason (usually because of memory). Just try restarting it and see if the problem persists. I've encountered this before and restarting Eclipse or the PC altogether usually solves it.

Comment: This problem occurred to me third time today, & eclipse restart time is 10 mins to , it wasted my half hour!

Comment: Shall we not make Eclipse more transparent and predictive?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I increased values of `-Xms` and `-Xmx` args to `512` and `2048` respectively in eclipse.ini file. You can increase it according to you or according to your system ram.
**And then restart eclipse.**

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Project** Menu **Uncheck** the **Build automatically** and **Restart** the **Eclipse**/STS IDE.

[image]

Comment: This solution is very efficient when the issue is persist after restarting the machine.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with the build path of the maven project. Try configuring the build path and include only what is actually required is what i learnt.
My parent maven project had 10+ child modules. My eclipse would take 3-4 mins waiting for background process for every file save. I removed [parent module]/src from the build path and restarted eclipse and issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try by creating a new workspace, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is persist after restarting the machine, probebly you have a loop of dependencies in your modules. I.e. there is a dependency deadlock between your modules, eg.  in PUM file of module1, it needs module2 and in PUM file of module2, it needs module1.
To solve the problem, verify your PUM files in your relevant modules or sub projects.