# unable to setup HTMLUNIT in eclipse

Tags: htmlunit

Please assist me in setting up htmlunit with eclipse. I am tryning to fill a form and submit it through the code

Here is my code

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

public class Ullas {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage)client.getPage("http://xx.com");
                HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) CurrentPage.getElementById("login_form");
                final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("nm");
                textField.setValueAttribute("mak");
                final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submitbutton");

                //currentPage = form.getAcceptAttribute();

                 button.click();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Some form of error happened !");
            }


        }

}
```

I did included all the libraries but when I run the application it keeps on saying "the user operation is waiting for'building workspace' too complete"

Comment: Eclipse can have a tendency to hang sometimes for no apparent reason (usually because of memory). Try restarting the application, if you already did it; does the problem persist?

Comment: Problem resolved but could you explain me how the above code should work means should it pop up the page that comes after the form is submited or what because when i am executing my code. It is doing nothing

Comment: The above code opens a webpage, inputs text and hits submit button. I assume you have directed it to right domain, then it should display the result.

Comment: Yes I have directed it to the correct domain but It doesn't display any result

Comment: It doesn't throw any error?

Comment: no it doesn't throw any error neither it shows any web page

Comment: Also, I am assuming you did write some tests? Here is the link for some sample tests: 

http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2011/05/16/htmlunit-a-quick-introduction/

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse has this weird tendency to hang (frequently due to memory). Most of the times restarting your instance can fix the issue. Alternately, running `eclipse.exe -clean` should also fix the problem as eclipse cleans all the cache data while starting. The problem has been reported by several users, I attaching links for your reference:

https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/myeclipse-hangs-on-building-workspace-0/

[User Operation is waiting for "Building Workspace"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514987/user-operation-is-waiting-for-building-workspace)

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/512454/

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=77946